# How to start Greeplum on boot - linux

Tags: linux, startup, systemd, greenplum, systemctl

Trying to start Greenplum on system startup. Please find systemd service file content below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Greenplum daemon
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/greenplum
User=gpadmin
Group=gpadmin
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "source /opt/greenplum-db-6-6.11.2/greenplum_path.sh"
#ExecStartPre=/opt/greenplum-db-6-6.11.2/greenplum_path.sh
ExecStart=/opt/greenplum-db-6-6.11.2/bin/gpstart -a -l /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs -d /greenplum/master/gpseg-1
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

All required environment variables are loaded and required path is sourced still not able to start service. Getting "ImportError: No module named gppylib.mainUtils".  After machine is started if I run start command(/opt/greenplum-db-6-6.11.2/bin/gpstart -a -l /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs -d /greenplum/master/gpseg-1) it is working fine. I am not able to understand what is going wrong. My current setup has two hosts(master and segment host). I have kept segment node up and trying on master. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sourcing `greenplum_path.sh` in `ExecStartPre` won't work because the environment isn't preserved between `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStart`. I would try something like

`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /opt/greenplum-db-6-6.11.2/greenplum_path.sh; gpstart -a -l /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs -d /greenplum/master/gpseg-1`.